# Entitlements file "Entitlements.plist" not found. error

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to run a simple app on an iPod touch. The code complies and runs on the emulator just fine, but as soon as I try to run it on the device I get the error above. I have run other applications this way and have tried different provisioning profiles. The Entitlements file is in the root of the project. I have also tried a wildcard id and a specific id as well. I am not sure what is happening.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a fix but probably more of a work around. If you restart Xamarin Studio the error will go away. see here http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11020/entitlements-file-entitlements-plist-not-found#latest

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studios you can add the Entitlements.plist file through right click on project.... Add (add new item) then start searching for Entitlements and you will see it.

Ref: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/107208/#Comment_107208

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I selected "Local Device" during the build. Once I changed to "Remote Device" or my actual device, the error went away.